# How to get Product details in magento observer (Order Save)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, event-observer

i am trying to get all the product in a order. i have the order details in my observer but i don't know how to get the product details from it. i have the following coding in my observer

```
public function getProducts($observer){
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 $data = $order->getData();
 $dumpFile = fopen('observer_working.txt', 'w+'); // file is creating
 fwrite($dumpFile, 'Sample text');
 return $this;
}
```

As you can see i am creating a txt file when order is placed. and it is working. and i have the order details also. but i am unable get the product id from it.

i need following data from the order details

1) Order id.

2) array of product id which is available in the order. (only product id is enough)

please help me to get those data.

Comment: You can get products using $order->getAllItems(), var_dump that data to see if you get what you need.

Comment: I'd recommend to start using xDebug, that way you can easily analyze the available object properties. (So you won't need to write to a txt file or var_dump)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order id is easy, as most models in Magento implement the getId() method:

```
$orderId = $order->getId();
```

Depending on whether you want all line items (configurable products will have 2) or just those that are visible, you can get a collection of order_items as follows:

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems(); // All line items
```

or

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems(); // All visible line items
```

These can then be iterated to get the product IDs:

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    $ids[] = $item->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$productIds = array();
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
}
```